# Finding the closest number equal to or greater than a given number

Tags: python, function

I have a python function in which I need to find the number in a list 'values' that's closest to a give number 'n' but that's greater than or equal to 'n'.

So far I have this:

```
def nearest_largest_value2 (n, values):
      closest = []
      for i in values:
        if i == n:
          closest = i
        elif (i > n) and (i-n < 2):
          closest = i
       return closest

print(nearest_largest_value2(5, [1,3,4,6,7]))
print(nearest_largest_value2(5, [7,6,4,3,1]))
print(nearest_largest_value2(5, [1,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

Problem is that I'm getting the answer I want for the first two print statements (6)
but I'm getting '6' for the last print statement when I want to get 5.

I'm new to Python but I thought once the first `if` clause was satisfied the code would stop.

Comment: You need to find the smallest difference between n and each of the values.

Comment: Once you have found `n` in the list, why do you keep looking?

Answer (score 2):

The condition `i-n < 2` is wrong. Instead, you should be checking if the current `i` is closer than the current `closest`. E.g.:

```py
def nearest_largest_value2 (n, values):
  closest = None
  for i in values:
    if (i >= n) and (closest is None or i < closest):
      closest = i
  return closest
```

**EDIT:**

An alternative way to describe the problem is to find the minimal value that's larger or equal than `n`. Describing the problem like that allows for a more "pythonic" oneliner:

```py
def nearest_largest_value2 (n, values):
    return min(v for v in values if v >= n)
```

**EDIT2:**

As @ekhumoro pointed out, the alternative solution presented in the previous edit will break if `values` does not contain any element that is equal to or greater than `n`. He also graciously offered a fix for it:

```py
def nearest_largest_value2 (n, values):
    min([v for v in values if v >= n] or [None])
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi `values[0]` isn't necessarily equal or greater than `n`. You could have an optimization here where you iterate the list until the first acceptable item without checking if it's the closest and then another loop from there on that does check if the element is closer

Comment: Why not just `i < closest`? Also, the alternative solution will break if every value is less than `n`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Good point wrt `i<closest`. Got caught up in OP's original implementation where I shouldn't have. Edited and improved, thanks!

Comment: @Mureinik One way to fix the alternative solution would be: `min((v for v in values if v >= n] or [None])`. Not very pretty, but at least it gives equivalent output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **multiple queries with different numbers, but to the same list**, then it's more efficient to first sort the list and then do a binary search on it.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

values = [7, 6, 4, 3, 1]

values.sort()

def nearest_largest_value2 (n, values):
    try:
        result = values [bisect_left (values, n)]
    except IndexError: # when number is > every element of list 
        result = None
    return result

print (nearest_largest_value2 (5, values)) # 6
print (nearest_largest_value2 (3, values)) # 3
print (nearest_largest_value2 (8, values)) # None
```

Let `p` correspond to `length of 'values' list` and `q` correspond to the `number of inputs 'n'` (or # times `nearest_largest_value2` is invoked).

In the **stated case**, Time Complexity of the previous solution is `O(pq)` whereas Time Complexity of the current solution is `O((p + q)logp)`.